# Errors is not printed out on resolve, ui-router

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have this in my module:

```
resolve: {
        user: function(UserLoader){
          return new UserLoader($stateParams.userId);
        }
      }
controller..
```

As you can see, I've not injected `$stateparams`, hence I fail to load the controller and the view. But why is the console not giving any errors on resolve as it does everywhere else? It can be a pain to debug if you have some logic in your resolve. Is it possible to "turn on" the console on resolve somehow?

Comment: I'd thought you'd get some sort of `can't access 'userId' of undefined`. Is `$stateParams` actually defined inside that function?

Comment: Noop, you get nothing. Just a blank page.

Comment: please add ui-router as tags in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation :

> $stateChangeError - fired when an error occurs during transition. It's important to note that if you have any errors in your resolve functions (javascript errors, non-existent services, etc) they will not throw traditionally. You must listen for this $stateChangeError event to catch ALL errors. Use event.preventDefault() to prevent the $UrlRouter from reverting the URL to the previous valid location (in case of a URL navigation).

You must listen on '$stateChangeError' event

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){ 
// an error occured, do something like $log.error(error) 
})
```

If you want to know more about ui-router event, check the api [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)